# Looking to understand if ULFM is part of the MPI standard and also any available implementations

Tags: mpi

Is ULFM part of the MPI standard now?. Looking to try out the fault-tolerant behaviour for some DL applications.

If not are there any known open source implementations of ULFM available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ULFM is not part of the MPI 3.1 standard.

An implementation based on Open MPI is available at http://fault-tolerance.org/ulfm/downloads